# Gaussian kernel representation

Tags: kernel-trick

I have seen in a few places (among others in question [Why Gaussian radial basis function maps the examples into an infinite-dimensional space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581508/why-gaussian-radial-basis-function-maps-the-examples-into-an-infinite-dimensiona), Artem Sobolev's answer) that the Gaussian kernel $K_G$ can be represented as follows $-$ $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^p \times \mathbb{R}^p$ and letting $\sigma = 1$:

$$K_G(x,y)=\exp\left\{-\frac{||x-y||^2}{2}\right\} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left\langle\sqrt[k]{\frac{f(x)}{k!}}x,\sqrt[k]{\frac{f(y)}{k!}}y\right\rangle^k$$

where:

$$f(x) = \exp\left\{-\frac{||x||^2}{2}\right\}$$

However, my understanding is that we then get:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left\langle\sqrt[k]{\frac{f(x)}{k!}}x,\sqrt[k]{\frac{f(y)}{k!}}y\right\rangle^k = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(\sqrt[k]{\frac{f(x)}{k!}}\sqrt[k]{\frac{f(y)}{k!}}\right)^k\left\langle x,y\right\rangle^k=f(x)f(y)\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left\langle x,y\right\rangle^k}{k!^{\mathbf{2}}}$$

Note that the $k!$ is squared, which is wrong $-$ the sum should be the expansion of the exponential function. Hence the correct formula should be:

$$K_G(x,y) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left\langle\sqrt[k]{\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{k!}}}x,\sqrt[k]{\frac{f(y)}{\sqrt{k!}}}y\right\rangle^k$$

Am I missing something? Or is the $1^{st}$ equation wrong? Any help will be appreciated!